# How to set substring statement as valid column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, where-clause

I have a code like the following:

```
INSERT INTO [TranslateValidate]..[Policy] ([BirthDate],[FirstName],[LastName])
  SELECT
    [Table2309].[DOB],
    SUBSTRING(Full_Name, CHARINDEX(',', Full_Name) + 2, LEN(Full_Name)),
    SUBSTRING(Full_Name, 0, CHARINDEX(',', Full_Name))  
  FROM [Table2309] AS [Table2309]
  WHERE [Table2309].[clientid] = (SELECT
    MIN(clientid)
  FROM Table2309 T
  WHERE T.Date_of_Birth = Table2309.Date_of_Birth
  AND T.Substring(Full_Name, CHARINDEX(',', Full_Name) + 2, LEN(Full_Name)) = Table2309.Substring(Full_Name, CHARINDEX(',', Full_Name) + 2, LEN(Full_Name))
  AND T.Substring(Full_Name, 0, CHARINDEX(',', Full_Name)) = Table2309.Substring(Full_Name, 0, CHARINDEX(',', Full_Name))
```

This would have an error message

> Cannot find either column "c" or the user-defined function or aggregate "c.Substring", or the name is ambiguous.

If I add [] for Substring part, this would should error message

> Invalid column name 'Substring(Full_Name,...

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: That statement isn't valid. To start with you are missing the table in your `INSERT` clause, you have a trailing comma (`,`) after your 3rd column expression (and there is *at least* one more issue)

Comment: Also, rather than T.Substring(...  try substring(T.FullName ...

Comment: As for the problem, functions are used like you have in the `SELECT`; they aren't used like methods in C#. I'm not sure *why* you have mixed up both syntax formats, when you've initially used `SUBSTRING` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma at the end of your select statement:

```
SELECT
    [Table2309].[DOB],
    SUBSTRING(Full_Name, CHARINDEX(',', Full_Name) + 2, LEN(Full_Name)),
    SUBSTRING(Full_Name, 0, CHARINDEX(',', Full_Name))**,**
```

Remove this comma and it should work fine.

Comment: That is part of the problem but definitely not all of the issues. The insert statement doesn't have a table it is inserting into, just a list of columns.